# Taxation on income deposited to US bank account

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india

I am a student in Florida USA and an Indian citizen. My income earned while I am outside US is not taxable in US. However, will such income be taxable if it is deposited to my US bank account?

The source of income will be a US company.

Comment: Please feel free to comment here if I need to furnish more information.

Comment: Will it be enough to push you over the standard deduction (currently $12000)?

Comment: Are you asking if the act of "moving cash from one bank to another" creates a taxable event?

Comment: @RonJohn, my total salary will be $15,000 earned during the 3 month summer internship. 

No, I am not asking about moving money at all. The money will be in the same US bank account to which it will be deposited.

Comment: Interest earned on bank savings accounts **is** taxable as normal income.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Whether income is taxable does not depend on what account the income is deposited into. And you can move money between your accounts freely without triggering taxes.